# Tengo el siguiente error con php, postgresql y highchart

Tags: postgresql-9.3

tengo el siguiente error lo que pasa es que realizo una consulta SQL la cual muestra una fecha en especifico para mostrar un grafico, y me da el siguiente error

pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo double precision: «'»

```
$resultado=pg_query("SELECT TO_CHAR(fechainfo_sector), sen_h_aminfo_sector FROM info_sectores WHERE year(`fechainfo_sector`) = '$ano' AND month(`fechainfo_sector`) = '$mes' AND day(`fechainfo_sector`) = '$dia' AND `chipinfo_sector`= '$chipinfo_sector'");
```

alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Intenta concatenando de la siguiente forma:

```
$resultado=pg_query("SELECT TO_CHAR(fechainfo_sector), sen_h_aminfo_sector FROM info_sectores WHERE year(`fechainfo_sector`) = ".$ano." AND month(`fechainfo_sector`) = ".$mes.". AND day(`fechainfo_sector`) = ".$dia." AND `chipinfo_sector`= '$chipinfo_sector'");
```